# Bug? Can't answer although I should have enough reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I wanted to add an answer to [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/what-female-mathematician-can-i-introduce-to-my-high-school-students) question but couldn't.  It is marked as *protected* and an answer "requires 10 reputation on this site".  However, it seems I have 101 reputation.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

The association bonus of hundred points that you got does not count in this context (by design). Thus, in the context of protected questions you have only one point.

I admit the documentation is not very clear here and this is a repeated source of confusion.
Yet it is there somewhat implicitly, namely it says: "[...] you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site." And, the idea is that the association-bonus is not points that were earned  on this site, but rather a welcome-gift.

But, again, I agree this is not very clear. Sorry, for the inconvenience.

Comment: This makes things quite confusing, then. Are there other things that the bonus points don't cover?